# Attach multiple event handlers with .on() and name spaces syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

When using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery you can attach multiple event handlers like so:

```
$("li").on({
  click: function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  },
  mouseenter: function(){
    $(this).addClass("inside");
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).removeClass("inside");
  }
});
```

You can also handle events using name spaces, like so:

```
$( 'li' ).on( 'click.toggles', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
$( 'li' ).off( 'click.toggles' );
//click.toggles is the name space?
```

**How do you you combine these two syntax? In hopes to easily turn off a set of multiple event handlers using [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/).**

Or am I totally not understanding namespaces and this is just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `on` you can write:

```
$("li").on({
  "click.namespace": function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  },
  "mouseenter.namespace": function(){
    $(this).addClass("inside");
  },
  "mouseleave.namespace": function(){
    $(this).removeClass("inside");
  }
});
```

And for `off` you can write

```
$("li").off(".namespace");
$("li").off("click.namespace mouseenter.namespace mouseleave.namespace");
```

Comment: can they share the same namespace and turn off at once?

Comment: They behave just like the usual bound event handlers.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include off() is this correct? and is there a better way to handle the syntaxs?